# Sign of difference of two convex functions

Tags: functions, convex-analysis

Suppose you have two continuous, 
convex functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$
 and $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.

Suppose that both $f$ and $g$ are minimised
 at $x=0$ with $f(0)<g(0)$. Furthermore,
 we know that: $g(x)\geq |x|+\beta$ and $f(x)\geq |x|+\alpha$ with $\beta>\alpha>0$ (In both cases, the equality holds only at the limit for $x\to\pm\infty$, otherwise those inequalities are strict).

My question is: do all these things together imply that

$$f(x)\leq g(x)\quad\forall x>0$$

---

Upon reflection, I can change $f(0)\leq g(0)$ to the stricter $f(0)<g(0)$ in the question statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. We can build a counter-example. The idea is to make  $f(0)$ and $g(0)$ really close together with $f(x)$ behaving like $sx+f(0)$ in some interval $[0,a)$ with $s\in (0,1)$ and $g(x)$ behaving like $g(0)+x^2$ on the same interval. If $g(0)$ is sufficiently close to $f(0)$, then the curves $g(0)+x^2$ and $sx+f(0)$ intersect in two points.

The convexity can be preserved on infinity for such an example, as well as the limiting behaviour. We can even make these functions $C^\infty$ and strictly convex.